# Does a duergar NPC need to concentrate to maintain its Enlarge ability?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, concentration, dwarf, duergar

In the MM page 122, nothing is mentioned about needing to maintain concentration, and there is no wording to indicate a duergar's Enlarge ability is a spell.

This is in contrast to the duergar's Invisibility action that explicitly says it must maintain concentration.

So, my interpretation is that this is some sort of innate magical ability, not a spell, and thus wouldn't require concentration. Is this about right, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Your interpretation is right

The enlarge ability is a magical ability, but it doesn't mention the necessity of maintaining concentration, neither does it refer to any spell (you might think of "Enlarge/Reduce", which would require concentration).
So **all requirements and all effects of this ability are mentioned in the action**.

It does not require concentration or components (verbal, somatic or materials).
The ability lasts one minute and can only used on himself.

Comment: Cool, thanks!A player was complaining how I wasn't having my duergar (I'm the DM) do concentration checks to maintain their Enlarge. I explained that it wasn't a spell and didn't work that way. He then whipped out the Sword Coast Adventurers Guide and pointed at page 104 where it talks about duergar as a playable race. In that entry it is explicitly a spell. I explained that there is a difference between a stat block in the MM and stuff created for characters to play. He didn't like this explanation.

Comment: You could point out for example, that drow *monsters* get poison crossbows, but drow *characters* don't have access to that particular poison. It is nowhere buyable in the PHB.  It is also re-usable, whereas PC poisons are generally 1 use. Likewise, all of the NPCs in the back of the MM use different rules than similar PCs. Monsters have different rules.