# How does the Duergar Magic shrink/enlarge ability work with rage?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, barbarian, rage, duergar

Is the Duergar's ability to shrink/enlarge considered a spell?

How does that combo off with the barbarian's "Rage" ability?

1. Am I able to do this after I go into a rage?
2. Does it cancel before I go into a rage?
3. Can this ability be *counterspelled*?
4. Does it require concentration to maintain? (I read on a previous note it doesn't require it and doesn't require ingredients to use)

Comment: Related: [Does a duergar need to concentrate to maintain its Enlarge ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83499/40921) which referes to Duergar monsters not PCs.

Comment: oooh thought there monsters and player race had the same perks when it came to this ability. Sorry about that.

Comment: Very related: [What counts as a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131495)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## It is a spell that is cast

The 3rd-level racial trait [Duergar Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/dwarf#GrayDwarfDuergar) states (SCAG, p. 104; emphasis mine):

> **you can cast** the *enlarge/reduce* spell on yourself once with this trait, using only the spell’s enlarge option...You don’t need material components for either spell, and you can’t cast them while you’re in direct sunlight, although sunlight has no effect on them once cast.

Unfortunately, being in a [Rage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#Rage-51) limits your spellcasting:

> If you are able to cast spells, you can’t cast them or concentrate on them while raging.

To answer your specific questions:

1. No, you can neither cast nor maintain concentration on a spell while raging.
2. Therefore, once you started raging, it would end.
3. It can be counterspelled because it's simply casting a spell. While it doesn't require material components, there are still verbal and somatic so it can be observed to be counterspelled.
4. It does require concentration because [Enlarge/Reduce](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) requires it and nothing in the racial feature counteracts or supersedes that.